# C# Moq Class with Interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, nunit, moq

I tried to make a `unit-testing` of a class `User`

I tried to do it with an interface, but I did not understand exactly what is and if it is the correct way to do the test, so:

My Class `User`

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public int id { get; private set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public IUser user;

    public User(IUser userI) // constructor with interface
    {
            user = userI;
    }

    public virtual bool MyFunction(string test)
    {
             if(test=="ping")
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
    }
}
```

My Interface `IUser`

```
public interface IUser
{
    int id { get; }
    string username { get; set; }
}
```

And then my Unit-test

```
[TestFixture]
public class MoqTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMyFunction()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IUser>();
        User user = new User(mock.Object);
        var result = user.MyFunction("ping");
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(true));
    }
}
```

The test result is correct and actually returns `true`, but do not understand the way of using the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically by mocking you create some kind of a dummy-implementation for that interface. So when calling `Mock<IUser>()` the compiler generates an anonymous class that implements the interface `IUser` and returns a new instance of this class. Now when creating your `User`-object you inject that dummy-object. The mocked object has no behaviour, all its members are set to to their default-value, it is only guaranteed that theay *are* set to anything. You can also change the values your members return but that won´t affect your example.

This way you can test the method you´re interested in without having to implement any external dependeines. This can be necessary because you have currently no working instance for the `IUSer`-interface and implement it later or because its initialization is quite heavy and you want to avoid initialize it within your tests (think of some database-logic included that does not affect your actual test, but would be needed to run the test).

In your case you could even use `new User(null)` as the method to be tested does not rely on an instance of that interface at all. So you won´t even have to mock it at all.